# Drag and drop upload - file not saved

Tags: php, ajax, html, file-upload

Im trying to make a drag and drop uploader work with my website and VPS i have.

Ive tried implementing it myself but couldnt make it work. Now Im trying to use "Mini AJAX File Upload Form" from http://tutorialzine.com/2013/05/mini-ajax-file-upload-form/

When i upload a file i can see that in fact my PC is uploading something. However, the php script seems not save save the file on the server. Ive tried modifying it but no success.

What i checked:

-Im sure the file is not saved on the server because I searched for the file AND I checked disk space after uploading a file

-No errors in apache log.

-php.ini upload limits are increased.

---

### edit:

Now Im trying to use jQuery File Upload (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) because it outputs errors. The error Im getting after uploading a 1 mb .png file is "File upload aborted".

Comment: Check the max file size in php.ini, I believe the setting is called upload_max_filesize

Comment: It would help a lot if you add an else to your if and output the error code. As Dai said it's most likely the file size which that would tell you.

Comment: Thanks for help but I checked php.ini already. I have it set on 100 M and i tried uploading files of various sizes (200 kb to 500 mb)
Every time i check folder where the file should be as well as disk usage statistics.

Comment: As for errors: I have a file that should store all errors but its empty. I set it up according to this: http://itslennysfault.com/force-php-to-show-all-errors-or-save-them-to-a-log-for-trouble-shooting

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue? Try setting the folder you're uploading to, to 777.

Comment: Yes it appears permissions was part of the problem. Ill post what fixed my problem as an answer in case anyone has a similar problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after research and trying different stuff out:

1. Make sure you check php.ini and increase the maximum size:
   post_max_size and upload_max_filesize
2. Even after setting the above 2 I had problems (errors saying that the file is too large even after i restarted the machine). To fix that create .htaccess file in the same dir as your .php file and paste the following inside:

   php_value upload_max_filesize 10M

   php_value post_max_size 10M
3. I changed permissions of all files and folders responsible for uploading to 777.

After those changes my files upload without any errors. Hope it helps somebody.